# Form Widget for CommaSeparatedIntegerField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a question in a form in which someone can select multiple options from the given set. Like so:

#### What is A?

1. B
2. C
3. D

Here, the person filling the form can select any combination of the 3 options. For example, B, C, BC, BCD

I am trying to store this information in the database.

One of the fields in my model is a CommaSeparatedIntegerField as follows:

```
class Tutor(models.Model):
    want_list = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=50, null=True,)
```

I created a form that uses this model like so:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):      
    class Meta:
        model = Tutor
        fields = ['want_list']
        widgets = {'want_list': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=P3_CHOICES),}
```

Since the default widget I got was a TextInput, I changed the widget to CheckboxSelectMultiple. I am using floppy-forms.

However, this way the data doesn't seem to validate. This is the error that I get:

"Enter only digits separated by commas."

...whenever I select any options and try to submit the form.

How do I fix this error? Am I using the wrong field in the model? Or the wrong widget in the form? What is the general way of achieving something like this? I imagine this is a common sort of thing done on many websites, and there must be some standard way of solving this that I don't know about.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
P3_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'B'),
    (2, 'C'),
    (3, 'D'),        
)
```

Comment: What is the value of `P3_CHOICES`?

Comment: Sorry. Added it to the question since this is relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `CheckboxSelectMultiple`'s value will be deserialized by Django to list a values (ex: `['1', '2']`), not to a comma separated integer list (ex: `'1,2'`) which `CommaSeparatedIntegerField` expects.

A solution is to make subclass of `CheckboxSelectMultiple` that does what you want:

```
class CommaSeparatedCheckboxSelectMultiple(CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    def value_from_datadict(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data_list = super(CommaSeparatedCheckboxSelectMultiple, self).value_from_datadict(*args, **kwargs)
        return ','.join(data_list)
```

Comment: I tried this code, but got a "name 'self' is not defined" error.

Comment: @AshishAcharya I edited my answer, it works now (first argument of `value_from_datadict` must be `self`)

Answer (score 0):

Although aumo's excellent answer solves my problem perfectly, I realized that I was trying to re-invent the wheel somewhat. So, I went searching and found a great Python package that does exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield/

Here's my implementation:

### models.py

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

P3_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'B'),
    (2, 'C'),
    (3, 'D'),        
)

class Tutor(models.Model):
    want_list = MultiSelectField(choices=P3_CHOICES, null=True)
```

### forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):      
    class Meta:
        model = Tutor
        fields = ['want_list']
```